# Почему метод normalizeEmail у express_validator удаляет точку в названии email?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

Стек технологий MERN (Mongo, Express, React и Node).
Есть форма авторизации, с полями email и пароль и две кнопки "Войти" и "Регистрация".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатие на кнопку "Войти", происходит вызов метода loginHandler() отправляющий запрос на бэк.

```
  const loginHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await request('/api/auth/login', 'POST', { ...form });
      message(data.message);
    } catch (e) {}
  };
```

На бэк запрос обрабатывается в файле auth.routes.js

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const config = require('config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const User = require('../models/User');
const router = Router();  
// Запрос на авторизацию пользователя
router.post(
'/login',
[
  check('email', 'Введите корректный email').normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
  check('password', 'Введите пароль').exists(),
],
async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array(),
        message: 'Некорректные данные при входе в приложение',
    });
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Пользователь не найден' });
  }

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!isMatch) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Неверный пароль, попробуйте снова' });
  }

  const token = jwt.sing(
    {
      userId: user.id,
    },
    config.get('jwtSecret'),
    { expiresIn: '1h' },
  );

  res.json({ token, userId: user.id });
} catch (e) {
  res.status(500).json({ message: 'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова' });
}
```

},
);

module.exports = router;

Валидацию полей обрабатываю, используя express-validator.js. Если в роуте использую метод normalizeEmail(), то в консоли бэк, если в email'е есть символ .(точка), получаю **testtest@gmail.com**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как только в роуте удаляю метода normalizeEmail(), то в консоле приходит корректный email **test.test@gmail.com**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просьба помочь разобраться, почему при использовании метода normalizeEmail, на бэке пропадает символ точки в названии email'a

Comment: Только для gmail? Или для других адресов тоже?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, проверил использовав test.test@mail.ru, отработало корректно. Странно конечно это

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=ru видимо библиотека очень умная

Comment: Но вообще, ну надо же читать документацию, а? Я вижу библиотеку впервые и за минуту нагуглил [gmail_remove_dots](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#sanitizers)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, благодарю